# He says/is saying that he has or had a dog". He asks me, what I am or what i was eating"

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, reported-speech, direct-speech

"He says/is saying that he has a dog" (but we cannot say, he says/is saying that he had a dog)
"He asks me what i am eating"(but we cannot say, He asks me what i was eating)

My assumption is that In reported speech if I reports someone with first form of verb as in "say,tell ask" instead of second form of verb as in"said",told,asked" then the following clause has to be in either present or future tense but not past tense. Do you agree with my assumption?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *He says he had a dog* or  *He is saying he had a dog*, so you must have misunderstood something. Nor is there anything "wrong" with *He asks me what I was eating* - it just requires a slightly unusual context to make sense. Perhaps you're getting confused because you've seen that native Anglophones often "backshift" reported speech, as in *He said his name was Smith* - despite the obvious facts that (1) what he actually said was "My name **is** Smith", and (2) his name **is still** "Smith" whemn reporting it later.

Comment: Could you please give us concrete examples instead of asking us to do mental gymnastics?? Thanks.

Comment: @Lambie my mistake.I  will be more clear next time.

Comment: If the question is about a meal you had earlier, you can certainly say "He asks me what I was eating (when he saw me at lunchtime)".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your assumption is mostly correct. When reporting speech in the present or future tense, it's common to use the present tense forms of verbs like "say," "tell," or "ask" instead of the past tense forms "said," "told," or "asked." The tense of the reporting verb determines the tense of the following clause, which is usually in the present or future tense when the reporting verb is in the present or future tense. However, it's also possible to use the past tense forms of the reporting verbs and have the following clause in the past tense, which can indicate that the speech being reported occurred in the past.

In general, the choice between using the present or past tense forms of the reporting verbs depends on the context of the situation and the speaker's intention in reporting the speech.

Comment: @BilalZafar: Your examples are so far-fetched it's difficult to conceptualise all possible differences between *how you eat 200 burgers* and *how you **will** eat 200 burgers*. But *one* difference is that the ***will*** version can more sensibly be used if the addressee has never done this (the version without ***will*** works better if addressee has done this once or many times in the past). But how often will you ever be in a real-world situation where such things matter? The examples are really just "toys" that wont actually *teach* much of anything.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you.Actually my prior query of this given answer by you,was deleted by me by mistake.I am reposting that query for other engkish learners. The query was(  For reporting speech in future can i use "Will" in following clause or it  when refering to future. As in "He will ask you how you will eat 200 burgers at once" or should i say "He will ask you how you eat 200

Comment: There's no *point* to using future tense *He **will** ask...* rather than past or present tense *(He **asked...*** or *He **is asking...)***. You're just complicating the issue for no reason. Whether the asking is past, present, or future doesn't *syntactically* affect the phrasing of what was, is, or will be asked about.